# Postgres recursive query - get path to root given a leaf node

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a leaf node in a tree structure and I need a Postgres query to recursively traverse the parent nodes to get me the full path to my leaf node.

My table looks like this - the problem being there is no specific root node (i.e the top-most managers end up reporting to each other)

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | manager_id | name  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 |          2 | Matt  |
|  2 |          1 | Simon |
|  3 |          1 | John  |
|  4 |          2 | Bob   |
|  5 |          4 | Bill  |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Given a user such as Bill `(id=5)` I'm after their reporting line:

`Matt > Simon > Bob > Bill` (ideally it just stops at Matt when it tries to go to a node already traversed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A recursive [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) is what you're looking for.

Data sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t 
(id INT, manager_id INT, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
(1,2,'Matt'),(2,1,'Simon'),
(3,1,'John'),(4,2,'Bob'),
(5,4,'Bill');
```

Query

```
WITH RECURSIVE man(a,b,c) AS (
  SELECT manager_id, id,name FROM t
  UNION 
  SELECT man.a, id,man.c FROM man, t
  WHERE man.b = manager_id)
SELECT a,c FROM man 
WHERE b = 5;

 a |   c   
---+-------
 4 | Bill
 2 | Bob
 1 | Simon
 2 | Matt
(4 Zeilen)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ef95298e87f5f7910fa77ad89cf631ba)